# Change fraction to decimal

Tags: decimal-expansion

Can anyone please help.
I'm following a tutorial found [here](http://easycalculation.com/analytical/orthocenter-triangle.php) as I have a situation where I have to get the equation of a line in point slope form i.e. $y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$

I get up to step 3 of the tutorial no problem, but then I got stuck.
In order to go from this equation $y−3=3/11(x−4)$ to this $11y−33=3(x−4)$ (getting rid of the fraction on the right), I have to multiply by 11 on both sides as suggested by members [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127443/how-to-find-the-equation-of-a-line)

However, my problem is that I wont be using fractions but floating point decimal numbers. So $0.272727$ rather than $3/11$.

My question is this, how can I get from this $y−3=0.272727(x−4)$ to $11y−33=3(x−4)$ in decimal form?

The reason for this is that I'm coding an application in C# and C# does not support fractions, only integers, float and double

Again, sorry if the tag is wrong but did not know where to post this as its probably a really simple question.

Comment: There is no good way to convert from float to rational numbers. On the other hand, there are fraction classes for C# (see, e.g., http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9078/Fraction-class-in-C). Maybe this solves your problem?

Comment: This is really a problem about coding, not mathematics, so it should go to another site.